# How can I deserialize JSON with a (.) in the variable name?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I am getting following payload and am not sure how to deserialize it properly.
Please note:  I already used the JSON2Apex and the provided code did not work for me.
Also, the actual payload is pretty big so I cannot keep using if-else to check token names and store values in local string and assigning it to fields .
I have a dynamic framework to map payload variables to SF fields. hence its a no to JSONtoApex.

```
{
    "payload.deal_id": "158968902749",
    "payload.delivery_date": "2017-03-08",
    "payload.deal": "Test Deal",
    "payload.revenue": 257800967,
    "payload.numValue": 0,
    "payload.anotherValue": 35
}
```

using the variable name as it is,

```
public String payload.deal_id {get;set;}
```

throws an error ....

```
Unexpected token '.'
```

Let me know if any one has an idea.
Thanks!

Comment: If you already have a proper mapping mechanism, you shouldn't need a huge if-else structure, just enough to pick out the object type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three basic fixes to any invalid identifier in your JSON keys are:

1. Deserialize untyped (`Map<String, Object>` in this case)

   ```
   Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(payload);
   String deal_id = (String)data.get('payload.deal_id');
   ```
2. Use string replacement.

   ```
   payload = payload.replaceAll('"payload.', '');
   ```
3. Roll your own JSON parser.

I strongly prefer the first option.

Comment: String deal_id = data.get('payload.deal_id');
should be 
String deal_id = (String) data.get('payload.deal_id'); 
as we cannot assign Object to String.

Comment: @brahmajitammana yes. you are correct. Else it will throw illegal assignment.

Comment: +1, but that string replacement would break json. instead: `payload = payload.replaceAll('"payload\\.(.+?)":', '"$1":');`

Comment: Actually I tested it on the very payload in the OP and it worked just fine.